# Fluid and Fixed Columns Table

Tags: html, css

I have a table on my layout that has 5 columns, 3 of them should be fixed width in px and the other 2 should be fluid.

It sounded simple at first, but the problem is the two fluid columns should behave differently.

The last column should stretch as much as it can to fit its contents, so they are never hidden, but shouldn't ever leave empty space. And the middle column should occupy all the free space it can find, but also overflow to hidden in case the last one needs to grow larger.

[image: Table diagram]

I tried to make this work with css, but I couldn't manage to make it work... Is there a way to do this with pure css or I need js?

**EDIT**

That's what I got so far:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="fixed">fixed</td>
        <td class="fixed">fixed</td>
        <td class="fluid hidden">fluid</td>
        <td class="fixed">fixed</td>
        <td class="fluid visible">this content should always be visible</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
    padding: 10px;  
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fixed{
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 60px;
}

.fluid{
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.visible{

}

.hidden{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzVbX/

It works almost as expected. Except for the last column.

Comment: Please add code / jsFiddle

Comment: Is that actual table data? In other words, does it have to be `table`?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell it is, indeed, tabular data.

Comment: @AndrewDonaldJohnson i really don't have much to show... so far, i only got a regular table markup :/

Comment: Providing markup for us to copy/paste gets you an answer faster.  Typing out all of the markup necessary for a 5 column table is a fair amount of work.

Comment: Hurrah, a css question that actually explains what they want! You win.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can help, maybe not.

First, I would use divs instead of tr/td. I honestly don't have a need for using tables since CSS was introduced, and I'm rather surprised that some people still do. But there could be a reason, so please do not take that as criticism.

If you use divs, then edit this section of your code:

```
.visible {
  overflow:visible;
  min-width: 210px;
}
```

That will make sure that the div is at least 210 pixels wide no matter what. It should work.
BTW, if this is the only table on the page and that div or td is unique in the sense that it has a minimum height, then you may want to use an id instead of a class. That will make your code cleaner and more elegant.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Keep in mind, `<table>` brings with it automatic-wins with regard to accessibility and SEO. All browsers, bots and screen-readers understand a proper table. If you replace a classic table with generic div's of your own making, you'll also have to provide mark-up with regard to aria-roles, labels, titles, tabindex, etc and even so you'll likely still miss some things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it is close to what you are looking for:

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/WGpB3/

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
            <td style="width:60px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:60px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="overflow:hidden;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:60px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="overflow:visible;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need wrapping do this:

```
td{
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

If wrap is desired, you need to change width of table to auto and add min-width parameter.

```
table{
   width: auto;
   min-width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made changes to CSS file

**DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/KzVbX/2/*

```
table{
   width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td{
    padding: 10px;
}

.fixed{
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 60px;
}

.fluid{
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.visible{
  overflow:visible;
}

.hidden{
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:20%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: still, the middle column doesn't hide on overflow... try resizing it and see

Comment: not exactly yet. there is remaining empty space on the last column.. but thank you for your help, if no one comes up with a fix for that, what we got now will have to do it :D